# VS code is not showing any of my folders in a directory

Tags: linux, ssh, nas, visual-studio-code

I have multiple remote machines setup in my university lab and I use ssh to connect to them. But using vs code remote on windows I can't access any of my folders on my NAS. When I use VS code in Linux I don't have any problems like this but in windows vs code absolutely refuses to acknowledge that there even is folders in that directory! I ticked off the compact folder and checked for exclusions the problem is not coming from there can anyone help me with this?

[As you can see in the image it's as if the NAS is completely empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb5R1.jpg)

I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Both my NAS boxes were working.  I updated one of them and it stopped working. The new firmware had unticked a setting.  I ticked it and it works.

On my Synology NAS it is

1. Control Panel
2. File Services
3. SMB
4. Advanced Settings
5. Others
6. Enable NTLMv1 authentication

It is supposedly a security risk  [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/security-guidance-for-ntlmv1-and-lm-network-authentication-da2168b6-4a31-0088-fb03-f081acde6e73).  The alternative is to change settings in Windows.  My problem was that the last thing I need is for dozens of applications to stop working.  So I have enabled it for now.